# Android: Disable recent apps intent

Tags: android, android-intent, quicklaunch

I want to disable the recent apps intent that is fired from the icon when you hold the home button. I am currently detecting, in the `onCreate()`, if the intent is fired from the quick launch dialog, and then I call `finish()`.

This entails that when the application goes to the background `finish()` is called so that when the app is launched it goes through the `onCreate()`. This requires strategic coding when switching between activities in the application.

I guess I can fire `finish()` in the `onResume()` also after detecting where the intent came from, but a bunch of unnecessary coding can be eliminated if the quick launch intent can simply be disabled.

Can the quick launch intent be disabled?

Comment: What is Quick launch intent? Is it the intent that is sent when clicking the app icon in home screen?

Comment: Its the intent fired from the icon in the dialog opened when you hold the home button.

Comment: Can you post the Intent Action that is received?

Comment: I am using the LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY flag to detect its launch from the recent apps dialog.

Intent intent = getIntent();
if((intent.getFlags()& Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY)!=0){
// Launch from recent app dialog!!!
}

A more elegant solution would be convenient.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can the quick launch intent be
>   disabled?

Put [`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) in the manifest for this activity. That will cause your activity not to appear in the list of recently used activities, which is what I am assuming you are calling the "quick launch".